# "Violation: Added non-passive event listener" when no JavaScript present

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, passive-event-listeners

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel'event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

I'm trying to understand this warning.

I've created the simplest of html files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="" id=""></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this in Chrome (Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)), and clicking on the select element shows the above error in the console:

[image: Violation Message]

I've done some brief reading of other posts and there's a lot of times this is due to frameworks or after the js code ran preventDefault() on the event.

However, in the above example there is no javascript running, so surely there should be no error? The [md doc referenced in the violation](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) text states:

> Developers can annotate touch and wheel listeners with {passive: true} to indicate that they will never invoke preventDefault

There are no `touch and wheel listeners` in the file above.

Comment: Maybe you have a chrome extension installed that's doing it? I don't see the warning in mine. (61.0.3163.100)

Comment: @zord, valid point - but I have all chrome extensions are disabled right now.

Comment: _I don't see the warning in mine._  ... Thanks @zord, that leads me to believe it must be some sort of local issue. I'll test on some other computers tomorrow.

Comment: @Stu I also don't see that issue. (same version, 61.0.3163.100)

Comment: @NathanHinchey thanks, that helps a lot guys, must be a local environment issue on my side then, it's been winding me up for a while!

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing... In fact this question came up as relevant when I was typing mine. I'll look at my extensions. Comforting to know that it's not in my code.  :)

Comment: this comes from chrome core not from an extension. After a new DOM specification for new browsers this is warning.